# from source to temp table and from temp table to permanent table SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to extract data from a table in server one. Then I want to create a staging table in server 2 using the following sql command.

```
if object_id('xTabKey', 'U') is not null drop table xTabKey
select top 0 * into xTabKey from dbo.rTabKey
```

Then I want to load data into this staging table. Finally, I want to copy data from staging to final table.
How can I do this using SSIS?
Thanks

First I used execute sql task to create the staging table. Then I use data flow task to extract data from the table in server 1. Now I am stuck. I can not select the staging table from OLEDB destination as I have not run the package yet.so the table is not created yet.

Comment: The best and easiest way to do this is create a permenant staging table not a temp one and truncate it just before you populate it every time.  Otherwise you have to change a lot more settings in SSIS like retain same connection (so temp table does not get dropped), and an option for Delay Validation I believe it was for the specific steps in SSIS.  Just WAY easier to use permeant stage table.

Comment: This temp table is dropped after executing the package. so, we cannot create Permanant staging table in the server 2. We want to automate this process.

Comment: Here is article that describes my other option above and keeping same connection/etc.   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/